# Using dialog from resources

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015

I have a VS Win32 C++ project. I have created a dialog using Resource->Add resource->Dialog. But I can't use it, there is no cpp file related to this dialog in my project. What I have done wrong? How to get hold of the cpp file for this dialog? Or must this dialog be used in a different way?

Comment: Sounds like you need Charles Petzold's Programming Windows 5th ed. https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/157231995X/sr=1-1/qid=1156801743/ref=sr_1_1/104-6313703-3867159?ie=UTF8&s=books

Comment: No, thank you. Question is not about .NET/C# programming.

Comment: Charles Petzold's Programming Windows 5th edition is the go to book for C Windows API programming with an entire chapter dedicated to dialogs like the question you are asking. However, if you cannot muster the reading comprehension to see `5th edition` instead of `6th edition` you might not make it far.

Comment: There are no classes in C. The Windows API is exposed through a C interface. You need Petzold's [Programming Windows®, Fifth Edition](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Win32 dialogs are just plain data (resources). In order to use them you need to spawn dialog using `CreateDialog` or similar function. You may find all the necessary information at [Dialog Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632588(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Hm, what about event handling inside the dialog box - button clicks, onCreate event, etc. ?

Comment: You need to pass a pointer event handling callback function into `CreateDialog`.

Comment: Dialogs gave a message procedure much like a window process messages in its message procedure. They are very similar. Again, if you plan on programming against the Windows API in native C++, you should read Charles Petzold's Programming Windows 5th ed. It is priceless in understanding windows and dialogs.